# Json Deserialization to Dictionary .NET

Tags: .net, json, serialization

Given json like this:

```
[
  ["Rating (out of 5)", "3"],
  ["Date taken", "Mon, 03 Mar 2003 03:04:03 GMT"]
]
```

What is the best way to deserialize it into something like `Dictionary<string, string>` or should I be using a different data structure?

I'd probably prefer to use the .net Serializer but will consider other options if this wont work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use one of the many [JSON parsers](http://json.org/) for C#.

Personally, I think [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) is very nice.  It supports LINQ queries against JSON data, serialization to/from JSON, etc.